# I'm trying to upload files with multer in node.js backend and react js in frontend but it doesn't work in back side with multer in public folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, multer

frontend with React.js looks good i saw the other people who did same thing as i did but i don't know where is the problem ! anyone can help me ?

```
    const [cours, setCours] = useState([]);
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("")
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("")
    const coursHandle = (e) => { setCours([e.target.files]) }

    const onsubmit = async (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();

       const formData = new FormData();
       formData.append("description", description);
       formData.append("title", title);
       // cours.forEach((elem) => { formData.append("cours", elem) });
       formData.append("cours", cours)
       // for (let i = 0; i < cours.length; i++) {
       //     formData.append("cours", cours[i])
       // }
       await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/upload", formData)
           .then((res) => console.log("successfully file post", res)).catch((err) => 
            console.log("error with file post", err))
   }
```

and backend with multer is here this code is in my app.js
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`
and the public folder is the same place as app.js

```
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

const MIME_TYPES = {
    "file/pdf": "pdf",
    "file/docx": "docx",
    "file/txt": "txt",
    "file/png": "png",
    "file/jpeg": "jpg",
    "file/jpg": "jpg",
}

const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "public");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const nameObject = path.parse(file.originalname);
        // const nameObject = file.originalname.split(' ').join('_');
        const extension = MIME_TYPES[file.mimetype];
        cb(null, nameObject.name.split(" ").join("_") + Date.now() + "." + extension);
    }
})

module.exports = { multerUpload: multer({ storage: fileStorage }).single("file") }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for my question,

```
formData.append("cours", cours)
```

Here the key name as i try to send is "cours" and :

```
module.exports = { multerUpload: multer({ storage: fileStorage }).single("file")
```

Here the key name for single function is "file" !! that was a first problem and another one was this :

I've forgoten to add this line in my  tag !

```
encType="multipart/form-data"
```

And finally my multer js is :

```
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "public/files");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log("filename :", file);
        const nameObject = path.parse(file.originalname);
        cb(null, nameObject.name.split(" ").join("_") + Date.now() + 
     nameObject.ext);
   }
})

module.exports = { multerUpload: multer({ storage: fileStorage }).array("cours") }
```

Answer (score 0):

In last line

```
module.exports = { multerUpload: multer({ storage: fileStorage }).single("file")
```

the argument under single is `file`, but in your frontend form there is no input with name file maybe you have to change the argument of single function from `file` to `cours`

Comment: @PeterSmith thanks Smith, but i have changed file to cours and the opposite doesn't  work  here is form submit `<input onChange={coursHandle} name='file' type="file" className="form-control" multiple required />`